# FormContext from react-hook-forms causing error in testing-library-react

Tags: react-testing-library, react-hook-form

Got an odd error with FormContext when trying to run my tests. All I'm trying to do is render a component.

[image]

So this is the error that I am getting and this is the test that I have written.

```
import React from 'react';
import UserReportQuestion from './UserReportQuestion';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { useForm, FormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

describe('(Component) UserReport', () => {
  let UserReportQuestionRender; 

  // jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => ({ 
  //   FormContext: jest.fn(),
  //   useForm: jest.fn(),
  //  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    const form = useForm();

    UserReportQuestionRender = render(
      <FormContext {...form}>
        <UserReportQuestion />
      </FormContext>
    )
  }); 

  it('Should render without crashing', () => {
    expect(UserReportQuestionRender);
  });
});
```

In the component I am testing I am using FormContext and passing it useForm as its methods. I've commented everything else out so it is just the FormContext in the component to make sure that it is 100% this that is causing the error.

Wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to work round this?

Update with component

```
  import { useForm, FormContext } from "react-hook-form";

  const UserReportQuestion = ({ text }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [isModalOpen, setModal] = useState(false);
  const methods = useForm();

  return (
    <>
      <Question>
        {t('UserReport.criteria')}:
        {' '}
        {/* Placeholder text */}
        {/* {text} */}
        Find new, creative ways of completing tasks

        <ModalIcon onClick={() => setModal(true)}>
          <Icon
            icon="info"
            color="#a3a3a3"
            modifiers={['size-large', 'solid']}
          />
        </ModalIcon>
      </Question>
      <InfoModal
        isModalOpen={isModalOpen}
        closeModal={() => setModal(false)}
        title={t('UserReport.modalTitle')}
      >
        <FormContext {...methods}>
          {/* <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit()}>
            <InfoModalParagraph>
              {t('UserReport.modalDescription')}
            </InfoModalParagraph>
            <FeedbackQuestions 
              questions={mockData}
              selfAssessment={false}
              submitButtonDisabled
              noSubmitButton
            /> 
          </form> */}
        </FormContext>
      </InfoModal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: what is the `UserReportQuestion` Components Codes?

Comment: I've added the code. The formContext is from react-hook-forms

Answer (score -1):

I think you're importing a component which doesn't exist, in the `react-hook-form` documentation we have a `FormProvider` if we want to use `useFormContext`.

read More about it here: https://react-hook-form.com/api/#useFormContext

but in the mean time you need to change

```
import {FormContext} from 'react-hook-form'
```

to this:

```
import { FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form'
```

Comment: Thanks but it does exist as we've been using it in other places:

Comment: `export declare function FormContext<T extends FieldValues>({ children, formState, errors, ...restMethods }: FormProps<T>): JSX.Element;`

Comment: Did you `export` the `UserReportQuestion` component?

Comment: yeah using `export default UserReportQuestion;`

Comment: So I don't think I could help anymore, good luck :) . if you found the answer plz mention me to check it.